# Is auto-refresh/update on opened variable/dataframe/series window supported in spyder?

Tags: python, dataframe, spyder

when you open a dataframe in spyder, and subsequently change something to this dataframe, the opened window is not being updated. 
You have to close it then re-open the dataframe in variable explorer. 
I saw someone had raised this potential functionality on the internet back in 2018 and they said they were going to try to make this happen in the future.
I am just wondering does the current spyder version have this feature already or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, This feature is not yet added. It still has an open issue in github

Here is the link to github issue: [Add ability to refresh/update existing Variable Explorer windows to reflect current variable state](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6325)

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly where I came from.